# Should I write "see THE attached invoices" or just "see attached invoices"?

Tags: articles

Please see the attached invoices and revised laytime.

I wonder if it should be:

> 1. Please see the attached invoices and revised laytime.
>      or
> 2. Please see attached invoices and revised laytime.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, I imagine that this is some manner of correspondence, so the following link doesn't apply entirely to your situation. However, [as you can see](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=see+attached%2Csee+the+attached&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csee%20attached%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsee%20attached%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSee%20attached%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSee%20Attached%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSEE%20ATTACHED%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsee%20Attached%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csee%20the%20attached%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsee%20the%20attached%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSee%20the%20attached%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSEE%20THE%20ATTACHED%3B%2Cc0), both versions of phrase are in regular use.

> See attached

is more common, but they're within an order of magnitude of each other. By specifying that the invoices are attached, you are making clear your intent as to which invoices you are referring. (Well, as long as you remember to attach them!) So using an article is not necessary. It is a matter of preference, and it appears that the majority prefer the brevity of omitting the article.